# Student attendance count by classwise

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have two tables

```
schoolname    StudentID     Class
A       1       1
A       2       2
B       3       1
B       4       2
C       5       1
C       6       2
C       7       3
```

and

```
StudentID   Attendance
1       present
2       Absent
3       Absent
4       present
5       present
6       absent
7       absent
```

i want result like

```
schoolname  class1      class2      class3      present     absent
A       1       1       0       1       1
B       1       1       0       1       1
c       1       1       1       1       2
```

class1,2,3,present and absent count based on studentid

**Sample Code:**

```
 ; with cte as 
    ( 
        select schoolname as [School Name]
        , count(studentid) as total 
        , class 
        from Student_Master 
        group by SchoolName
        , class 
    ) 
select [School Name]
,isnull(1,0)1 
,isnull(2,0)2
,isnull(3,0)3 
from cte 
pivot (sum(total) for [class] in (1,2,3) ) as p
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, contrary to what your friends told you.

Comment: is this a paid service

Comment: @venkateshcodetree Can you please add more details? What server are you on? What version? Do you have any code from your attempts at the desired output?

Comment: SO encourages you to try something yourself and then ask for help afterwards.  Otherwise, questions and answers have a tendency to become meaningless and unhelpful.

Comment: @tarheel this is sql server 2012 version and i had tried this               with cte as(
select schoolname as [School Name],count(studentid) as total ,class from Student_Master

group by SchoolName,class
)
select [School Name],,isnull(1,0)1 ,isnull(2,0)2,isnull(3,0)3
from cte 
pivot
(
sum(total)
for [class] in (1,2,3)
) as p                                                                                                i am getting only classwise count am not getting total present and absents school wise

Comment: @venkateshcodetree Check out my answer below. Also, since this is your first post, I'll tell you 2 things. 1) When an answer is the right one, you should officially accept the answer (click the checkmark). 2) Take a look at this page for some guidance on how to ask high quality questions on stackoverflow. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Answer (score 2):

I used table variables for the sake of ease on my side, but you can easily substitute permanent table names in your final solution.

**Sample Data Setup:**

```
declare @student_master table 
    (
        schoolname char(1) not null
        , studentid int not null
        , class int not null
    )

insert into @student_master values ('A', 1, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('A', 2, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('B', 3, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('B', 4, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 5, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 6, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 7, 3)

declare @student_attendance table
    (
        studentid int not null
        , attendance varchar(10) not null
    )

insert into @student_attendance values (1, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (2, 'Absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (3, 'Absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (4, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (5, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (6, 'absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (7, 'absent')
```

I then used the following query to get the desired output.

**Answer:**

```
; with classes as 
    (
        select post.schoolname
        , isnull(post.class1, 0) as class1
        , isnull(post.class2, 0) as class2
        , isnull(post.class3, 0) as class3
        from (
            select sm.schoolname
            , 'class' + cast(sm.class as varchar(4)) as col_nm
            , count(*) as col_val
            from @student_master as sm
            group by sm.schoolname
            , sm.class
            ) as pre
        pivot (sum(pre.col_val) for pre.col_nm in ([class1], [class2], [class3])) as post
    )
    , attendance as
    (
        select sm.schoolname
        , sum(case when sa.attendance = 'present' then 1 else 0 end) as present
        , sum(case when sa.attendance = 'absent' then 1 else 0 end) as [absent]
        from @student_attendance as sa
        inner join @student_master as sm on sa.studentid = sm.studentid
        group by sm.schoolname
    )
select c.schoolname
, c.class1
, c.class2
, c.class3
, a.present
, a.[absent]
from classes as c
inner join attendance as a on c.schoolname = a.schoolname
```

**Output:**

```
schoolname  class1  class2  class3  present absent
A             1       1        0       1      1
B             1       1        0       1      1
C             1       1        1       1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to take any credit from @Tarheel, just a little different approach.

```
declare @student_master table 
(
    schoolname char(1) not null
    , studentid int not null
    , class int not null
)

insert into @student_master values ('A', 1, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('A', 2, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('B', 3, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('B', 4, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 5, 1)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 6, 2)
insert into @student_master values ('C', 7, 3)

declare @student_attendance table
(
    studentid int not null
    , attendance varchar(10) not null
)

insert into @student_attendance values (1, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (2, 'Absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (3, 'Absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (4, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (5, 'present')
insert into @student_attendance values (6, 'absent')
insert into @student_attendance values (7, 'absent')


SELECT  schoolname, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS Class1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN class = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS Class2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN class = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS Class3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sa.attendance = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Present,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sa.attendance = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Absent
    FROM @student_attendance AS sa
        INNER JOIN @student_master AS sm ON sa.studentid = sm.studentid 
    GROUP BY schoolname

Output:
schoolname  Class1  Class2  Class3  Present Absent
    A         1      1       0        1       1
    B         1      1       0        1       1
    C         1      1       1        1       2
```